# Is there a way to search the web and my own hard drive at the same time?

Tags: windows-search, search-engines, desktop-search, google-search

I have lots of PDFs and other documents on my hard drive, many of which aren't online anywhere.

If I know something is online, I can use Google.

If I know something is on my drive, I can use Windows Search and find it.

But is there a browser extension or external tool that would let me search for a phrase and show me Google results side-by-side with results from my own hard drive?  Actually, if I could also search my GMail, Google Docs, etc at the same time without mirroring them to my drive first, that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

The old Google desktop search used to do this but that is discontinued http://googledesktop.blogspot.com/. You might want to check out this [comparison of desktop search products](http://www.wikinfo.org/index.php/Comparison_of_desktop_search_software)

Answer (score -1):

Open an EVERNOTE Account and save all those PDF's to EVERNOTE.
While configuring EVERNOTE make sure to tick "Use Simultaneous search"
When enabled, your searches on supported search engines like GOOGLE will 
also be performed on your Evernote account.

Comment: I'm not uploading my entire hard drive to Evernote.  :)